# Java: Program with FileReader

Tags: java, file-io, filereader

Try as I might, I cannot figure out how to solve this program. I apologize for its cheesiness, I'm a student learning java and was given this as a practice.

```
Lixnor is a mutant space trader in the Andromeda IV galaxy. He is low on 
supplies and funds and has trouble paying for the fuel that his ship 
requires. Every SGW (Standard Galactic Week) his partner, Ronxil gives him 
the coordinates for 2 valuable lost crates floating in space. The 
coordinates are sent in a file named "Coordinates.txt". The files always 
have 3 lines, each line containing a coordinate in the format (x,y,z) where 
x,y,z are integers. Due to Lixnor's lack of funds, he must first calculate 
whether it would be worth it for him to go pick them up. The first 
coordinates given are Lixnor's current coordinates, and the next two are the 
coordinates of the two crates. Lixnor must pick them up, then return to his 
original location. Write a program for Lixnor that calculates the distance 
he must travel in order to pick up the crates and return to his original 
position.

(24,-34,46)

(1,2,3)

(123,-1,0)
```

Specifically, I'm having trouble getting Java to read the file. Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: learn Java File reader. Try to do it, and come back with some code. Then we might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a file is simple

- Get the file instance using `File file = new File(String fileAddress);`
- Now use `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);` to read the file.

Proceed and show us the work for further help.

I agree with @ImGeorge that before doing this work get some basic knowledge about File Reader.

*At SO we cannot help without code.*

Answer (score 0):

Look into the javadoc of [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-).

```
Path path = Paths.get(".... .txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); // Using UTF-8
```

This is one of the possibilities. The processing is up to you.